# php soap server prefijo en elementos

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Estoy programando un servidor soap con php, el código:

```
$options = array('uri' => 'http://myserver/wsdl', 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 );
$server = new SoapServer("http://myserver/wsdl/wsas.wsdl", $options );
$server -> setClass("myclass"); 
$server->handle();
```

Que funciona perfecto con una estructura estandar:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://myserver/wsdl.php">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:element1>
         <subelement1>
            <subId1>?</subId1>
            <subName1>?</subName1>
         </subelement1>
         <subpart>
            <subIdp>?</subId1>
            <subNamePart>?</subName1>
         </subpart>
    ...
```

El archivo de definicion de estructura wsas.wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsas="http://myserver/wsdl.php" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="wsas" targetNamespace="http://myserver/wsdl.php">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://myserver/wsdl.php">
      <xsd:element name="element">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="subelement1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="subId1" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xsd:element name="subName1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="subpart" minOccurs="0" maxoccurs="unbounded">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="subIdp" type="xsd:int"/>
                  <xsd:element name="subNamePart" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
...
```

Pero la estructura enviada por el cliente es distinta, además obligatoriamente 
 debe ser wsas:element (con el prefijo wsas). He intentando poniendo alias, cambiando nombre, definiciones y no doy con la solución.

Como puedo obtener "wsas:element"?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Recién publique un repositorio que es lo que necesitas:

https://github.com/WookPlay/SOAP

Revisa bien el READ.md, hay esta toda la información detallada de como usarlo.